# Awkward Array: Fancy indexing with boolean mask along named axis

Tags: arrays, python-3.x, numpy, python-xarray, awkward-array

I have a dataset of 2D audio data. These audio fragments differ in length, hence I'm using Awkward Array. Through a Boolean mask, I want to only return the parts containing speech.

## Table mask attempt

```py
import numpy as np
import awkward as aw

awk = aw.fromiter([{"ch0": np.array([0, 1, 2]), "ch1": np.array([3, 4, 5])},
                   {"ch0": np.array([6, .7]), "ch1": np.array([8, 9])}])
# [{'ch0': [0.0, 1.0, 2.0], 'ch1': [3, 4, 5]},
#  {'ch0': [6.0, 0.7], 'ch1': [8, 9]}]

awk_mask = aw.fromiter([{"op": np.array([False, True, False]), "cl": np.array([True, True, False])},
                        {"op": np.array([True, True]), "cl": np.array([True, False])}])
# [{'cl': [True, True, False], 'op': [False, True, False]},
#  {'cl': [True, False], 'op': [True, True]}]

awk[awk_mask]
# TypeError: cannot interpret dtype [('cl', 'O'), ('op', 'O')] as a fancy index or mask
```

It seems that a `Table` cannot be used for fancy indexing.

## Array mask attempts

### Numpy equivalent

```py
nparr = np.arange(0,6).reshape((2, -1))
# array([[0, 1, 2],
#        [3, 4, 5]])

npmask = np.array([True, False, True])
nparr[:, npmask]
# array([[0, 2],
#        [3, 5]])
```

### Table version attempt; failed

```py
awk[:, npmask]
# NotImplementedError: multidimensional index through a Table (TODO: needed for [0, n) -> [0, m) -> "table" -> ...)
```

Seems multidimensional selection is not implemented yet.

### JaggedArray - Numpy mask version; works

```py
jarr = aw.fromiter(nparr)
# <JaggedArray [[0 1 2] [3 4 5]] at 0x..>

jarr[:npmask]
# array([[0, 2],
#        [3, 5]])
```

### JaggedArray - JaggedArray mask version; works

```py
jmask = aw.fromiter(npmask)
# array([ True, False,  True])

jarr[:, jmask]
# array([[0, 2],
#        [3, 5]])
```

## Questions

- How to do efficient boolean mask selection with `Table` or with named dimensions (like [xarray](http://xarray.pydata.org/en/stable/))?
- Will multidimensional selection in `Table` be implemented in `awkward-array`, or only in `awkward-1.0`?

## Library versions

```py
print("numpy version  : ", np.__version__)  # numpy version  :  1.17.3
print("pandas version : ", pd.__version__)  # pandas version :  0.25.3
print("awkward version : ", aw.__version__)  # awkward version :  0.12.14
```

Answer (score 1):

This is not with named array dimensions, but with only JaggedArrays, masked selection is possible:

```py
jarr_2d = aw.fromiter([[np.array([0, 1, 2]), np.array([3, 4, 5])],
                       [np.array([6, 7]), np.array([8, 9])]])
# <JaggedArray [[[0 1 2] [3 4 5]] [[6 7] [8 9]]] at 0x7fc9c7c4e750>

jarr_2d_mask = aw.fromiter([[np.array([False, True, False]), np.array([True, True, False])],
                            [np.array([True, True]), np.array([True, False])]])
# <JaggedArray [[[False True False] [True True False]] [[True True] [True False]]] at 0x7fc9c7c1e590>


jarr_2d[jarr_2d_mask]
# <JaggedArray [[[1] [3 4]] [[6 7] [8]]] at 0x7fc9c7c5b690>
```

Not sure if this code is efficient? Especially compared to fancy indexing with only Numpy arrays?

Comment: `fromiter` should be considered inefficient in Awkward 0.x (but not in Awkward 1.x).

Comment: What would be the efficient way of doing this in Awkward 0.x @JimPivarski ?

Comment: Also, this doesn't solve the initial question, as it doesn't work on `Table` arrays.

Comment: (I used a comment, rather than an answer, because I didn't have time to fully answer the question but wanted to give some information.)

Comment: (Since I posted quite a long question, it's quite common to not read everything in detail. Therefore, I wanted to attend with my comment that this is not a final answer. @JimPivarski Thanks for providing even a little bit of extra information, and indeed this .fromiter() is slow for big arrays. Please let me know if there is a more efficient way, if you have time to answer.)